# Can portable oil-filled heat radiators be stored on their side?

Tags: storage

I just bought a surplus lot of 30 portable oil-filled radiators that turned out to be laid flat on their sides *(the orientation of the individual boxes were not visible)*. So debate arose that I gambled and lost because they are ruined and will not function.

My understanding is they are sealed oil reservoirs so orientation doesn't matter and they could've been upside down and it wouldn't have mattered. The oil is still viable and can be heard gurgling towards gravity when the heaters were put upright.

What is the best way to store them?

Comment: Usually boxes will have an arrow on them if contents should be store a specific way.  If not, would store them as if they were in use.

Comment: What is the specific model of the heater?

Comment: That was one of the first things I looked for. No indicators on any packaging, But it certainly common sense.  I don't know if the pallet was re-stacked after the factory or not.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus They aren't all the same but the majority of them are Pelonis HO-17LA1W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be filled with oil, not tar, so 5 minutes of standing upright should let enough oil settle down to the heating element for safe operation.

Snap, crackle, and pop noises are quite common when starting up these heaters for the first time during the season. These noises can last about half an hour.

I couldn't find a Pelonis HO-17LA1W instruction manual but I did find one for [HO-0264](http://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/d9d9948d-d7f0-4878-8d5b-b624036932ef/08512274.pdf) and I found it makes no mention of required upright storage but on page 3 it nonchalantly states:

> Note: This heater includes a safety tip-over switch, which will shut the heater off in case it is tipped over. If at any time, the heater does tip over, **please put the heater back in the upright position** (wheels on bottom, controls on top). The heater will resume its normal operation.

This would indicate to me that storage orientation is a non-issue. Just make sure it's upright when plugged in and heating.

Comment: I would think it i safe to say this is a good disclaimer for all oil-filled heaters.

Comment: @GWarner Not necessarily. You should always read the owner's manual. I couldn't find a manual for the specific model you mentioned but found a manual for HO-0264 so I added it to my answer. Hopefully it's similar enough or you find the same nonchalant instructions to just place the heater upright.

Comment: I will add anything I learn later. I. didn't open any boxes but restacked them upright on more pallets wrapped and strapped already. Easy enough to open one later.